# How to set up a web service for a post request in php

Tags: php, web-services, .htaccess, apple-push-notifications

I am setting up Safari push notifications and they send a response to a endpoint that they choose.

I need to set up a web service backend to account for this.

They POST a token to:

`/v1/devices/<deviceToken>/registrations/<websitePushId>`

How do I set up my backend, using rewrites, or something... to capture the `deviceToken` and `websitePushId`?

I have a php script to add this info to a database. I just don't know how to get the POST info, and those two parameters into that script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Search PHP apache url rewrite

Comment: lokes like GET not post to me

Comment: Please do not ask same questions over and over.

Comment: Sorry hjpotter92. Didn't realise they were going to be the same until I worked out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So it actually isn't that difficult when I got the right syntax.

If anyone wants to know in the future. This is how you can do it.

```
RewriteRule ^v1/pushPackages/(.*?)$ /API/SafariNotifications/$1/v1/pushPackages/createPushPackage.php [L]

RewriteRule ^v1/devices/(.*?)/registrations/(.*?)$ /API/SafariNotifications/$2/v1/devices/registerUsers.php?deviceToken=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^v1/log$ /API/SafariNotifications/log/log.php [L]
```

Then in those php files, you can write your magic and return what you need to return.

In the device token rewrite. it will actually POST through the data, as well as add the GET param. So you can access both in your file.

This is for setting up *Safari Push Notifications Web Service Back End*.

Hope this can help someone in the future.